# LoganSquare parsing Android library : feedback, benchmarks, pros, cons

Tags: android, json, android-parser, logan-square

I'm using **Jackson** with DataBind library to parse json and map it java object. I'm also using Gson on other project where perf is less required.

On 17 Feb, [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) library is first released, promising 4-10 time faster parsing as Gson.

- **What advantages as LoganSquare than Gson/Jackson didn't have ?**
- **Pros and cons ?**
- **Do you have benchmarks in production application ?**
- **Is is stable enough for a production app?**

*I understand it can be a primarly opinion base question, so be as technic and specific as possible and base your answer on real data.*

Comment: you have all answers in first paragraph of  README.md

Comment: I wanted to have informations about other developers that those who are developping it. @Selvin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well to be clear if you are releasing your app to devices with ART  you will have a huge speed advantage trough parsing.

so i will explain my experience with logansquare so far.

pros :

- **Easy to use**: with Gson you have to use Type for parsing json array to a object list, in loganSquare it is so easy as `LoganSquare.parseList()`
- **Faster** : in any device (test it yourself) it is slightly faster.
- **FasterER**: in ART devices its speed gap is really giant  see their benchmark
- **RetroFit friendly**: yeah it plays well with retrofit.

cons :

- **NO REALM DB** : I could't make it run with Realm db so far(I didnt tried hard yet)
- **Custom Type Adapter** :Couldn't find a type adapter or something similar so far but I am not sure.

see their benchmark [here](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare/blob/master/docs/benchmarks.jpg)

and here is my poor benchmark results(it is not  a proper benchmark but it is something):
Emulator nexus 5, with DalvikVM,4.2 jellybean

#### Benchmarks

[image: parsing time sheet]

[image: parsing time graph]

#### Parsed model

```
import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonField;
import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Ercan on 6/26/2015.
 */
@JsonObject(serializeNullCollectionElements = true ,serializeNullObjects = true)
public class Village {

    @SerializedName("IdVillage")
    @JsonField(name ="IdVillage")
    String tbsVillageId;

    @SerializedName("TBS_VillageId")
    @JsonField(name ="TBS_VillageId")
    String townRefId;

    @SerializedName("VillageName")
    @JsonField(name ="VillageName")
    String villageName;

    @SerializedName("Status")
    @JsonField(name ="Status")
    String status;

    @SerializedName("DateInserted")
    @JsonField(name ="DateInserted")
    String dateInserted;

    @SerializedName("DateLastModified")
    @JsonField(name ="DateLastModified")
    String datelastModified;

    public String getTbsVillageId() {
        return tbsVillageId;
    }

    public void setTbsVillageId(String tbsVillageId) {
        this.tbsVillageId = tbsVillageId;
    }

    public String getTownRefId() {
        return townRefId;
    }

    public void setTownRefId(String townRefId) {
        this.townRefId = townRefId;
    }

    public String getVillageName() {
        return villageName;
    }

    public void setVillageName(String villageName) {
        this.villageName = villageName;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getDateInserted() {
        return dateInserted;
    }

    public void setDateInserted(String dateInserted) {
        this.dateInserted = dateInserted;
    }

    public String getDatelastModified() {
        return datelastModified;
    }

    public void setDatelastModified(String datelastModified) {
        this.datelastModified = datelastModified;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have run [LoganSquare Benchmark](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare/tree/development/BenchmarkDemo) project on my Nexus 5 device with Android 6.0.1 and here is the result:

[image: LoganSquare Benchmark screenshots]

Also, after a short time spend with the lib, here are my pros and cons:

**Pros**

1. is really fast in both parsing and serialization
2. small library size
3. handy methods for lists parsing and serialization
4. useful converters
5. compile-time errors instead of run-time only

**Cons**

1. not much of a documentation, also not many questions & answers on
   StackOverflow :)
2. not many types supported
3. only String keys supported in Map collections

I wrote an [example project](https://github.com/lomza/LoganSquare-Example) to see how LoganSquare works and also a [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-parse-json-with-logansquare/), so take a look there for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`response.body()` it is string json response

// MovieData it is a model Class

```
 MovieData movieData=LoganSquare.parse(response.body(),MovieData.class);

 Log.d("onResponse: ",movieData.getTitle());
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

The library is not updated since 4+ years.

It was working mostly fine till now but according to my knowledge it will stop working after gradle 5.

Comment: what makes you say that? Please provide links to back your claims.